# airflow PostgresOperator report number of inserts/updates/deletes

Tags: python, postgresql, airflow

I'm exploring replacing our home-build SQL file orchestration framework with apache airflow.

We currently have extensive logging on execution time, history and number of records `INSERTED`/`UPDATED`/`DELETED`. The first two are supported by Airflow standard logging, however, I could not find a way to log the resulting counts of the operations.

What would be the way to log these? Preferably by sql file? And how make them visible in a nice graph?

My simple exmaple DAG looks like this:

```
with DAG(
    dag_id="postgres_operator_dag",
    start_date=datetime.datetime(2023, 2, 2),
    schedule_interval=None,
    catchup=False,
) as dag:

    proc_r= PostgresOperator(task_id='proc_r',
                             postgres_conn_id='postgres_dbad2a',
                             sql=['001-test.sql','002-test.sql'])


    proc_r
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, `PostgresOperator` is deprecated. You should use `SQLExecuteQueryOperator` (see [source code](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/39caf1d5bc5ec5ff653cf00b25d45e176709b59e/airflow/providers/postgres/operators/postgres.py#L85-L91)).

I raised a [PR](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/29954) to address this which is expected to be released in next version of `apache-airflow-providers-common-sql`.

For [`apache-airflow-providers-common-sql>1.3.4`](https://pypi.org/project/apache-airflow-providers-common-sql/#description):

```
SQLExecuteQueryOperator(
    ...,
    show_return_value_in_logs=True
)
```

For [`apache-airflow-providers-common-sql<=1.3.4`](https://pypi.org/project/apache-airflow-providers-common-sql/#description):

The operator does not support printing to log, it can only push to xcom the result value. You can handle it by writing a custom operator (Noting: It require to override a private function which is risky! so use this with judgment)

```
from airflow.providers.common.sql.operators.sql import SQLExecuteQueryOperator

class MySQLExecuteQueryOperator(SQLExecuteQueryOperator):
    def _process_output(self, results: list[Any], descriptions: list[Sequence[Sequence] | None]) -> list[Any]:
        self.log.info("result is: %s", results)
        return results
```

Running:

```
MySQLExecuteQueryOperator(task_id='some_sql',
                          conn_id='postgres_default',
                          sql="SELECT 4*5"
                          )
```

Will give:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the ultra quick-reply :). Having this is the log is great! Ideally, I would like to be able to chart these values as well. Maybe xcom would be preferable for that?

Comment: Xcom is used to pickup small data by downstream task (branching decision or something like that). I don't know what you are after but it sound more like you want to transmit the output somewhere and build monitoring to track the values over time.. that is more in a whole another domain.

Comment: Good question : ) What I'm after is comparing the #inserts etc for a specific SQL between runs. So, for example if a run has on average 10,000 inserts, and the current run has 0, that probably is sign something is wrong. So just as we can track the duration of a step, it is useful to track/chart the summary-of-operations . But I support I could write a stap that collects all these xcom-output for the previous steps in the DAG and use that to fill a summary_table of some sorts.

Comment: Write downstream task that pull xcoms from last X runs. Calculate current run value againt previous one with any threshold calculation you like and then decide what to do in case of failure. Maybe for example send email/notification